# Animate AVPlayerLayer transform property

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-animation, avplayerlayer

I wan't to reproduce Live Photo zoom effect with `AVPlayerLayer`. For this purpose I use `VideoView`:

```
class VideoView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }

        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that whenever I try to change `transform` property of the view or of the layer during the video playback, nothing changes. But the changes are applied later after the playback finishes.

Animation example:

```
func zoomIn() {
    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 0.2,
        delay: 0,
        options: .allowAnimatedContent,
        animations: {
            self.transform = .init(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
    },
        completion: { _ in
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `AVPlayerLayer` ignores many of `CALayer` properties and the only way to scale a `VideoView` is to change it's `frame`.